# Two errors with code when I try to connect Iphone simulator with raspberry pi

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I just started learning swift and xcode and I am using a tutorial I found online to connect my raspberry pi to my iphone (link to tutorial: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=196010). However, I am getting stuck when I try to connect it as I keep getting errors. The two errors I get are:

1. libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2. Thread 1: signal SIGABRT (in the app delegate class)

Also, this all happens when I try to click the connect button. Although I am not sure if this is related, there is a warning on the connect button, "Result of call to 'connect()' is unused." However, when I go to the main storyboard, it seems correct as I did the control+drag to move from the main storyboard button to the view controller swift and made it a UIButton, Action, and named it the same. Below is my code for the View Controller class.

[View Controller code][1]

```
import UIKit
```

import CocoaMQTT

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
//Instantiating a CocoaMQTT as a mqttClient
let mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "iOS Device", host: "192.168.0.28", port: 1883)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func gpio40SW(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn {
        mqttClient.publish("rpi/gpio", withString: "on")
    }
    else {
        mqttClient.publish("rpi/gpio", withString: "off")
    }
}


@IBAction func connectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mqttClient.connect()
}

@IBAction func disconnectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mqttClient.disconnect()
}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your code here as well? Im unable to access the link.

Comment: Yes, no problem!